# Wrong printer adress in cups

Tags: network-printer, cups

I want to connect to my printer connected to a host in my local network running cups.
I managed to add the printer via the webinterface. The printer was successfully located and listed in the add printer form.

After adding the printer the status is `Idle - "Unable to locate printer."`

cups/printers.conf contains `DeviceURI dnssd://Kyocera%20FS-1020D%20%40%20hal9000._ipp._tcp.local/cups?uuid=59de77d2-18d2-3ca3-710c-18df97bf2abf`.

The address looks suspicious to me. The actual FQDN of the printserver is hal9000.wg.lan

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue.  My server name sharing them is "galactica" and all the printers get connected after discovery as "galactica.local" which doesn't resolve.  Have you found a solution?